# How can I access an Array within a Hash?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am building an installer for perl modules we require at work. After all of the dependencies are installed, I need to check if the module is working properly "use This::Module". The problem is, all of the modules are being installed within a certain order.

The hash looks like...

```
my %modules=(
                0  => {'name' => '/root/mods/CGI/perl-FCGI-0.74-8.amzn2.0.2.x86_64.rpm', 'method' => 'rpm', 'status'=>'pending'},
                1  => {'name' => '/root/mods/CGI/perl-CGI-3.63-4.amzn2.noarch.rpm', 'method' => 'rpm','status'=>'done', 'validate' => ['CGI','CGI::Carp']},
                
                2  => {'name' => '/root/mods/Digest/perl-Digest-1.17-245.amzn2.noarch.rpm', 'method' => 'rpm','status'=>'pending'},
                3  => {'name' => '/root/mods/Digest/perl-Digest-MD5-2.52-3.amzn2.0.2.x86_64.rpm', 'method' => 'rpm','status'=>'done', 'validate' => ['Digest::MD5']},
                
                4  => {'name' => '/root/mods/HTTP/perl-Business-ISBN-Data-20120719.001-2.el7.noarch.rpm','method' => 'rpm','status'=>'pending'},
                5  => {'name' => '/root/mods/HTTP/perl-Data-Dumper-2.145-3.el7.x86_64.rpm','method' => 'rpm','status'=>'pending'},
                6  => {'name' => '/root/mods/HTTP/perl-Business-ISBN-2.06-2.el7.noarch.rpm','method' => 'rpm','status'=>'done'}, 'validate' => ['HTTP::Request::Common']},
```

Each newline is the start of a new module. Once one the 'status' => 'done' I need to access the  modules within 'validate'. This is an array because there are cases where there are multiple modules tied to one install sequence.

How can I loop through and return each array element by itself?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you encounter problems?

Comment: I tried iterating over the hash's index, then through validate, but each time I would get nothing returned. I was able to successfully print the array contents with "print @{$modules{1}{'validate'}};" but I am not able to successfully loop through the array.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> 'validate' => {['CGI','CGI::Carp']}},
> ```

You don't have arrays.

The value of `validate` is between `{` and `}` so it is a hashref.

The arrayref is the first entry in the hash, so it gets converted to a string to be used as a key.

You end up with something like:

```
{
      'name' => '/root/mods/CGI/perl-CGI-3.63-4.amzn2.noarch.rpm',
      'method' => 'rpm',
      'status' => 'done',
      'validate' => {
                      'ARRAY(0x7f9ab601c4e0)' => undef
                    }
};
```

**Make sure you `use strict;` and `use warnings;`**. It would have alerted you to this:

> Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at Untitled.pl line 9.

---

You need to fix your data structure. If you want an array, then put it in an array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;

my %modules = (
    0 => {
        'name'   => '/root/mods/CGI/perl-FCGI-0.74-8.amzn2.0.2.x86_64.rpm',
        'method' => 'rpm',
        'status' => 'pending'
    },
    1 => {
        'name'     => '/root/mods/CGI/perl-CGI-3.63-4.amzn2.noarch.rpm',
        'method'   => 'rpm',
        'status'   => 'done',
        'validate' => [ 'CGI', 'CGI::Carp' ]
    },
);
```

Then you can access the arrayref:

```
my $arrayref = $modules{1}->{validate};
```

and loop over it:

```
foreach my $value (@$arrayref) {
    say $value
}
```

Comment: I see what you are saying, but I am still getting "Not an array reference". Is there something else wrong with my array?